# Can I issue a 'select exists' that checks for ALL specified fields?

Tags: sql

Say that I have a database:

```
TITLE        |    RUNTIME    |    EPISODES
-------------------------------------------
The X-Files         42              202
Fringe              NULL            100
Seinfeld            21              NULL
```

I want to issue a statement like `SELECT EXISTS(SELECT title,runtime,episodes FROM shows);` that will return 1 if all three of those fields are present (as for The X-Files) but 0 if any of them are empty/null (as with Fringe and Seinfeld).

Is this possible using SQL alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest just doing:

```
select t.*,
       (case when title is not null and runtime is not null and episodes is not null
             then 1 else 0 end) as HasAllThree
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `EXISTS` function checks if rows exist, not columns. You can add a `WHERE` clause to meet your business objectives with the `EXISTS` and a `CASE`.

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM shows
        WHERE title IS NOT NULL
            AND runtime IS NOT NULL
            AND episodes IS NOT NULL
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: Please let me know any feedback for the downvote. I'd be happy to address the concern.